# Update de varios registros con resultado de subconsulta

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Buenas estoy intentando hacer algo que creía que debía ser muy simple (y que seguro que lo es)
pero no lo consigo, cabe decir que todo es a modo de aprendizaje.
Tengo una tabla:

```
id int,
valor varchar(20)
```

con los datos

```
id valor
1  null
2  null
3  null
4  null
```

Queria actualizar en un solo update todos los registros de valor por 'row_'+ su id, pero no lo consigo, pego la consulta con la que lo estoy intentando:

```
update tabla_p  set valor = 
(select 'row_' + CONVERT(varchar(3),tg.id) from tabla_p as tp where tp.id = id  )
```

¿Podéis echarme una mano por favor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el escenario que indicas.

```
Create table tabla_p (id int, valor varchar(20));
go
Insert into tabla_p(id, valor)
values
(1,null),
(2,null),
(3,null),
(4,null);
```

Para poder actualizar los registros con un literal, para la fila en cuestión, solo tienes que recurrir directamente a su columna, de manera que le indicas que valor estableces y tienes cualquier dato, de cualquier otra columna de la misma fila, sin necesidad de realizar subconsultas.

```
Update tabla_p 
    set valor = CONCAT('row_',Cast(id as varchar(3)));
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]